# Multiprocessing a pandas DataFrame with checks including global Variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, global-variables

I run windows 11 and use this code in Visual Studio code

- I need to test 100 samples with the predict method of my code. The predict takes some time and seemingly could be parallelized as nothing changes on my variables and no interdependence exists.
- Although for the predict there is a global variable needed, this would need to be accessible for all of the cores I guess.
- Afterwards I just want the results obviously
- I tried debugging it but as soon as I hit the map() it just runs for ever and my debugging interface get's empty.
- If I run it as a single thread it works fine.
- What am I missing?
- Is it still the global variable of hlcs/hlcs_clean etc.? I thought with the args declaration it would work?
- If additional info is need just say so
- I had the num_process dynamically but I read this isn't the real number. But it gave me 24 back and I have 12 physical cores

---

```py
import Mains.Main_deap as md
import numpy as np
import statistics as stat
import timeit
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

# Set the parameters
size_array_pool = 1  # Set the size of the seed
runs = 500  # Set the number of runs
num_best_individuals = 100  # Set the number of best individuals to select

# Set the parameters for the Genetic Algorithm
crossover_probability = 0.5  # Set the crossover probability
mutation_probability = 0.4  # Set the mutation probability
population_size = 200  # Set the population size
num_generations = 100  # Set the number of generations

# Read the clean data for comparison
hlcs_clean, llcs_clean = md.read_file("data/file_li.csv")

# Define error-related variables
number_of_errors = 1
error_types = ["value", "negiert", "index"]
selected_error_type = 1
error_type = error_types[selected_error_type]

# Define a function to process samples in parallel
def process_sample(sample):
    if md.predict(hlcs, llcs, sample) != md.predict(hlcs_clean, llcs_clean, sample):
        return {'error_found': 1, 'error_not_found': 0}
    else:
        return {'error_found': 0, 'error_not_found': 1}

# Start timing the execution
start = timeit.default_timer()

# Initialize results dictionary to store error counts
results_deap = {
    'error_found': 0,
    'error_not_found': 0
}

# Main loop for running the genetic algorithm and evaluating samples
for r in range(runs):
    j = 0
    hlcs, llcs = md.read_file("data/file _li.csv")
    
    # Create errors in the data
    while j < number_of_errors:
        feedback = md.create_single_error(llcs, error_type)
        if feedback is None:
            continue
        else:
            j += 1

    # Suppress PerformanceWarning
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=Warning)
    array_pool = llcs.get_n_samples_with_labels_random(size_array_pool)
    array_pool = md.convert_df_from_standard_to_01(hlcs, llcs, array_pool)
    array_population = array_pool.values
    
    # Run the genetic algorithm
    algorithm = md.deap_algorithm(array_population, crossover_probability, mutation_probability, num_best_individuals, population_size, num_generations, hlcs)
    best_individuals = algorithm.run_algorithm()
    
    warnings.resetwarnings()

    # Print information about the best_individuals array
    if check:
        print(type(best_individuals[1]))
        print(f"best_individuals.shape: {best_individuals.shape}")
        print(type(best_individuals))
        check = False

    # Try to run sample evaluation in parallel
    pool_results = []
    num_processes = 12
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
    args_list = [(sample, hlcs, llcs, hlcs_clean, llcs_clean) for sample in best_individuals]
    pool_results.extend(pool.map(process_sample, args_list))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Update the results_deap dictionary with error counts
    for result in pool_results:
        results_deap["error_found"] += result['error_found']
        results_deap["error_not_found"] += result['error_not_found']

# Stop timing the execution
stop = timeit.default_timer()

# Print the runtime
print(f"Runtime: {(stop - start)/60} minutes")

This is the output:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
best_individuals.shape: (100, 1087)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

`

Comment: You need the `__main__` guard, see "why the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part is necessary" in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html - you should also have 1 Pool object - currently your Pool creation is inside a for loop.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @Booboo I am running windows 11 and VSC so I can not use this one function with shed that only runs on Linux iirc, if that's where your question ist headed

Comment: I was not headed anywhere in particular. See the comment posted by @jqurious. If you are running Windows, then In your main script any code at global scope that either directly creates a child process (or processing pool) or indirectly does so by calling a function that does so must be enclosed within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.